# software creator that is using shortcuts inside an other

Tags: user-interface, ide, open-source

I am wondering if there is any software that can create a software with shortcuts inside another?

Like if you want to make an web editor you cold say that if you press that button it will write:

```
<html></html>
```

And use a browser to render?

If there is no software like this, is it possible to make?
Maybe I am wrong, but I think it will be a breakthrough for opensource development.

I am not a skilled developer so that I won't manage to make something like this, but I want to start a group to do this, with making a website for it. Do  you think someone wants to help me or maybe one of you?

I have searched the web for something like this but haven’t found anything.

**Edit:**

---

I know this was  quite bad formulated and  am going to explain this again.
And what I mean is not a web editor, but a software developer application.
The web designer was just a example.

Imagine yourself that you have a UI designer whose you can import other software’s in and then you drag a button in to the screen, and on the settings you say that when you click that button the software will go into one of the software’s you’d imported and do something.

The software I am asking for is this software developer software.

**Edit again:**

---

I will do a second attempt to clarify:

You know about bots right? Those who fly around on the web and to crazy things as cheeking  hotel prizes to playing poker.

I only wonder about if you cold make a new GUI like QT or GTK that would emulate a certain keyboard event or mouse gesture when clicking a button. And were to get started when doing so.

Comment: This isn't what Stack Overflow is for. You'll have to find another forum to drum up interest in your project or recruit people. I should warn you though that you appear to be talking about WYSIWYG editors, of which there are several. This isn't a "breakthrough", it's mostly a horrible idea, and every person who cares at all about producing good software avoids WYSIWYG HTML editors like the plague.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/kompozer-problems-733285/#post3580690

There's several powerful web editors in a list composed by someone there.  It includes editors with a WYSIWYG.

Aptana studio is what I use which can use different browsers to render.  It also has a built-in web server so that you can test AJAX requests and php rendering.